# kapt plugin not working with gradle-script-kotlin

Tags: build.gradle, kotlin, vert.x, kapt

I want to move my vertx based project to https://github.com/sczyh30/vertx-blueprint-microservice.git template. The blueprint project uses annotations @vertxGen etc. to generate code during compilation.

I am using gradle-script-kotlin to build the project. I need to use kapt plugin to generate code as per annotations (via vertx ... codegen ). Unfortunately, am unable to correctly configure kapt plugin. Its giving following error:

**w: [kapt] Sources output directory is not specified, skipping annotation processing**

I would be delighted if someone could fix my gradle build file. Following are the kapt related snippets

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.* // kaptExtension
...
apply {
  plugin("kotlin-kapt")
}
...

fun Project.kapt(setup: KaptExtension.() -> Unit) = the<KaptExtension>().setup()

kapt {
        generateStubs = true

        javacOptions( closureOf<KaptJavacOptionsDelegate> {
                option("-proc:only")
                option("-processor", "io.vertx.codegen.CodeGenProcessor") // vertx processor here
                option("-AoutputDirectory", "${projectDir}/src/main")
                option("-Acodegen.output", "${projectDir}/src/main")
        } )

        // specify output of generated code
        arguments( closureOf<KaptAnnotationProcessorOptions> {
                arg("destinationDir", "${buildDir}/generated/source/kapt/main")
        } )
}
...
java {
...
        sourceSets.getByName("main").java.srcDirs("${project.buildDir}/generated/source/kapt/main")
}
```

Let me know for any other info/query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add following to the build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
....
        kapt("io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertx_version:processor")
...
}
```

Still dont know why though. posting here to let others know.

Comment: Kotlin docs say you have to use the `kapt` configuration 
in you dependencies the way you did it https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart from kotlin-kapt plugin and other kotlin dependencies keep following dependencies in your build.gradle file. It will be enough to generate the code(I am using the same way). Above mentioned kapt and java blocks are not required unless you are looking for some customization.

```
dependencies {
  kapt "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion:processor"
  compileOnly "io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion"
}
```